# Product display on Commerce Kickstart 2

Tags: commerce

Trying to set up Kickstart2. On the Product display grid the word **From** appears before the price. I need to remove this but as yet can't find where it is in the code. Its in a span class of price_prefix. Having searched the code I have found two files where it does appear but changing these and clearing the cache does not remove it. The files tried so far are 
commerce_kickstart_product.features.field_instance.inc
and
commerce_kickstart_lite_product.features.field_instance.inc
What I would like to happen is for my term reference used for that product to be shown after the price, so how do I then set term ref field_weight to show up

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you can't just change code in random files and expect it to reflect in changes on the front end. It's not recommended from a maintenance standpoint assuredly, as you will lose your customizations on the next module or distribution upgrade anyways.

In this case, the "From" prefix is coming from the field display settings on the product variation types defined by Commerce Kickstart 2.x. For the "Node: Product List" view mode, Kickstart 2.x is using the "Price with Prefix / Suffix" display formatter provided by the [Commerce Extra Price Formatters module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_extra_price_formatters). You can view the configuration in a Kickstart 2.x install using demo content at the following path:

> /admin/commerce/config/product-variation-types/bags-cases/display/node_product_list

To get rid of the prefix, you can either edit the settings for the display formatter there or change it completely to use the "Formatted amount" display formatter. That's the default display formatter in Drupal Commerce, and it will not have a prefix or suffix.

Once you make the change, though, keep in mind that the Commerce Kickstart Product feature is now overridden. If your deployment process includes a step that reverts all features, you will lose this configuration change. Saving your features updates is a topic for another thread, but it's going to be complicated by the fact that you'll need to override a feature defined by a distribution. If I were you, rather than depend on the default features modules provided by Kickstart 2.x, I'd learn how the distribution built things and build them yourself from scratch. If you can't do that, then just ensure that you avoid reverting features from here on out.